# How do I call a different subroutine using parameters passed into the current one (for use in recursion)?

Tags: c++, assembly, recursion, x86

I have two functions that take integers x and y read from input.

product returns x * y

power returns x ^ y, however it uses recursion and product to compute this. so x would be "base" and y is "exponent".

They called from C++:

```
int a, b, x, y; 
a = product(x, y);
b = power(x, y);
```

and here is the asm. I got the product to work, however am having trouble with power because I am not sure of the syntax/method/convention to call product from it (and call itself for the recursion). EDIT: Recursion must be used.

```
    global product
    global power

    section .text

product:

    push  ebp       
    mov   ebp, esp  

    sub esp, 4  

    push edi    
    push esi    

    xor   eax, eax

    mov edi, [ebp+8]        
    mov esi, [ebp+12]   

    mov [ebp-4], edi        

product_loop:
    add [ebp-4], edi        
    mov eax, [ebp-4]                                    
    sub esi, 1          
    cmp esi, 1      
    jne product_loop        

product_done:
    pop esi         
    pop edi         
    mov esp, ebp    
    pop ebp         
    ret             

power:

    push  ebp       
    mov   ebp, esp  

    sub esp, 4  

    push edi    
    push esi    
    push ebx    

    xor   eax, eax  

    mov edi, [ebp+8]        
    mov esi, [ebp+12]       

    ;;;

check: 
    cmp   esi, 1            ; if exp < 1 
    jl  power_stop          

recursion:                  ; else (PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!)
    ; eax = call product (base, (power(base, exp-1)) 

power_stop: 
    mov eax, 1              ; return 1 

power_done:
    push ebx        
    pop esi         
    pop edi         
    mov esp, ebp    
    pop ebp         
    ret
```

EDIT: My solution!

```
power:
    ; Standard prologue
    push  ebp       ; Save the old base pointer
    mov   ebp, esp  ; Set new value of the base pointer

    sub esp, 4  ; make room for 1 local variable result

    push ebx    ; this is exp-1

    xor   eax, eax  ; Place zero in EAX. We will keep a running sum

            mov     eax, [ebp+12]           ; exp
            mov    ebx, [ebp+8]             ; base
            cmp     eax, 1                  ; n >= 1
            jge     L1                      ; if not, go do a recursive call
            mov     eax, 1                  ; otherwise return 1
            jmp     L2
    L1:
            dec     eax                     ; exp-1
            push    eax                     ; push argument 2: exp-1
            push    ebx                     ; push argument 1: base
            call    power                   ; do the call, result goes in eax: power(base, exp-1)
            add     esp, 8                  ; get rid of arguments
            push eax                        ; push argument 2: power(base, exponent-1)
            push ebx                        ; push argument 1: base
            call product                    ; product(base, power(base, exponent-1))
    L2:

    ; Standard epilogue

    pop ebx         ; restore register
    mov esp, ebp    ; deallocate local variables
    pop ebp         ; Restore the callers base pointer.
    ret             ; Return to the caller.
```

Comment: 1st: You are not using recursion here.

Comment: Is this just an exercise? Compiler generated code will be faster than this...

Comment: Yes, this is just an exercise. @Artur That may be so, but I am trying to! I am not sure how.

Comment: Just `push` parameters on the stack and `call` product subroutine. Return value will be on stack too (`pop` it after `call`). That said...why recursion? You're using a loop, it's not recursion (and it's not needed). To do recursion you have to call `power` from within itself, your `recursion` label is meaningless. Call `product` then `push` new operands for `power` and call it again until stop condition is satisfied (recursion...)

Comment: @Tidus - first practice calling convension use - write simple function taking 2 ints and returning one. Depending on calling convension you must add some code to the caller as well - see you routines invocation in disassembly and read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions. If you do not manage to do it for tomorrow I'll help you ;-)

Comment: I have restored the old version of this question, since we ask that questions are preserved in their original state for the benefit of future readers. If you have a particular reason for removing it, please ping me via `@halfer` and I'll try to advise you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [*CDECL*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) calling convention, so you have to first push the arguments in the stack in backward direction, then call the function and then clean the stack after the return.

```
         push   arg_last
         push   arg_first
         call   MyFunction
         add    esp, 8      ; the argument_count*argument_size
```

But here are some notes on your code:

1. Your function `product` does not return any value. Use `mov eax, [ebp-4]` immediately after `product_done` label.
2. Multiplication is much easy to be made by the instruction `mul` or `imul`. Using addition is the slowest possible way.
3. Computing the power by recursion is not the best idea. Use the following algorithm:

   1. Y = 1;
   2. if N=0 exit.
   3. if N is odd -> Y = Y*x; N=N-1
   4. if N is even -> Y = Y*Y; N=N/2
   5. goto 2

Use `SHR` instruction in order to divide N by 2. Use `test` instrction in order to check odd/even number.

This way, you simply don't need to call `product` from `power` function.

Comment: Ah, I missed `mov eax, [ebp-4]` in the loop. But you never use it actually, so better remove it from the loop. Actually it is better to stop using [ebp-4] at all and use eax register as a variable. And the best is to not use loop at all. :) Use `mul` or `imul`.

Comment: 1. Wasn't this done in the product_loop label? In product_done, I was doing things like restoring registers, deallocating local variables, restoring the base pointer, etc for convention. 
2-3. I'm aware these are terrible ways to do these things, but it was an exercise in trying to wrap my head around it all. Could you show me how it'd be done with recursion? Basically I was trying to implement this: http://www.gidforums.com/showpost.php?p=34627&postcount=2 in my power function

Comment: @TidusSmith - No, sorry. The bad practices have to be discouraged from the beginning. :)

Comment: Check my solution. Is that a little better? To be honest I'm just happy it works :), but I could I should learn how to do it right sooner than never. What I REALLY needed to know and seem to have discovered  is that the parameters that are passed in are just whatever was at the top of the stack upon call it seems? And yes, it is terribly slow. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure how to write the assembly, you can generally write it in C++ and assemble it for clues - something like:

```
int power(int n, int exp)
{
    return exp == 0 ? 1 :
           exp == 1 ? n :
           product(n, power(n, exp - 1));
}
```

Then you should just be able to use `gcc -S` or whatever your compiler's equivalent switch for assembly output is, or disassemble the machine code if you prefer.

For example, the function above, thrown in with `int product(int x, int y) { return x * y; }` and `int main() { return product(3, 4); }`, compiled with Microsoft's compiler ala `cl /Fa power.cc`:

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01

        TITLE   C:\home\anthony\user\dev\power.cc
        .686P
        .XMM
        include listing.inc
        .model  flat

INCLUDELIB LIBCMT
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  ?product@@YAHHH@Z                               ; product
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_x$ = 8                                                 ; size = 4
_y$ = 12                                                ; size = 4
?product@@YAHHH@Z PROC                                  ; product
; File c:\home\anthony\user\dev\power.cc
; Line 1
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
        imul    eax, DWORD PTR _y$[ebp]
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
?product@@YAHHH@Z ENDP                                  ; product
_TEXT   ENDS
PUBLIC  ?power@@YAHHH@Z                                 ; power
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
_TEXT   SEGMENT
tv73 = -8                                               ; size = 4
tv74 = -4                                               ; size = 4
_n$ = 8                                                 ; size = 4
_exp$ = 12                                              ; size = 4
?power@@YAHHH@Z PROC                                    ; power
; Line 4
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 8
; Line 7
        cmp     DWORD PTR _exp$[ebp], 0
        jne     SHORT $LN5@power
        mov     DWORD PTR tv74[ebp], 1
        jmp     SHORT $LN6@power
$LN5@power:
        cmp     DWORD PTR _exp$[ebp], 1
        jne     SHORT $LN3@power
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _n$[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR tv73[ebp], eax
        jmp     SHORT $LN4@power
$LN3@power:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _exp$[ebp]
        sub     ecx, 1
        push    ecx
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR _n$[ebp]
        push    edx
        call    ?power@@YAHHH@Z                         ; power
        add     esp, 8
        push    eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _n$[ebp]
        push    eax
        call    ?product@@YAHHH@Z                       ; product
        add     esp, 8
        mov     DWORD PTR tv73[ebp], eax
$LN4@power:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR tv73[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR tv74[ebp], ecx
$LN6@power:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR tv74[ebp]
; Line 8
        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
?power@@YAHHH@Z ENDP                                    ; power
_TEXT   ENDS
PUBLIC  _main
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_main   PROC
; Line 11
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
; Line 12
        push    4
        push    3
        call    ?power@@YAHHH@Z                         ; power
        add     esp, 8
; Line 13
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

To walk you through this:

```
?power@@YAHHH@Z PROC                                    ; power
; Line 4
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 8
```

The above is the entry code for the power function - just adjusting the stack pointer to jump over the function arguments, which it will access below as `_exp$[ebp]` (that's `exp`) and `_n$[ebp]` (i.e. `n`).

```
; Line 7
        cmp     DWORD PTR _exp$[ebp], 0
        jne     SHORT $LN5@power
        mov     DWORD PTR tv74[ebp], 1
        jmp     SHORT $LN6@power
```

Basically, if `exp` is not equal to 0 we'll continue at label `$LN5@power` below, but if it is 0 then load `1` into the return value location on the stack at `tv74[ebp]` and jump to the function return instructions at `$LN6@power`.

```
$LN5@power:
        cmp     DWORD PTR _exp$[ebp], 1
        jne     SHORT $LN3@power
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _n$[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR tv73[ebp], eax
        jmp     SHORT $LN4@power
```

Similar to the above - if exp is 1 then put n into eax and therefrom into the return value stack memory, then jump to the return instructions.

Now it starts to get interesting...

```
$LN3@power:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _exp$[ebp]
        sub     ecx, 1
        push    ecx
```

Subtract 1 from exp and push in onto the stack...

```
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR _n$[ebp]
        push    edx
```

Also push n onto the stack...

```
        call    ?power@@YAHHH@Z                         ; power
```

Recursively call the power function, which will use the two values pushes above.

```
        add     esp, 8
```

A stack adjustment after the function above returns.

```
        push    eax
```

Put the result of the recursive call - which the power return instructions leave in the eax register - onto the stack...

```
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _n$[ebp]
        push    eax
```

Also push n onto the stack...

```
        call    ?product@@YAHHH@Z                       ; product
```

Call the product function to multiple the value returned by the call to `power` above by `n`.

```
        add     esp, 8
        mov     DWORD PTR tv73[ebp], eax
```

Copy the result of `product` into a temporary address on the stack....

```
$LN4@power:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR tv73[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR tv74[ebp], ecx
```

Pick up the value from that tv73 temporary location and copy it into tv74...

```
$LN6@power:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR tv74[ebp]
```

Finally, move the the `product()` result from  tv74 into the eax register for convenient and fast access after the `product` call returns.

```
; Line 8
        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
```

Clean up the stack and return.

Comment: Right. I know how to do this in C++, but I don't know how to do it in assembly. So I have my product function which works fine, but in my power function, I need to call product AND have it call itself? I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: @TidusSmith: what I'm saying is that you can ask the C++ compiler how it arranges this in assembly language... check the edits above....

Comment: I see what you mean. To be honest, I am a complete beginner, so all of that really just looks like a foreign language to me. I will do my best to figure it out. :(

Comment: Tidus Smith: it's scrapy, but simple if you bear with it.  I'll walk you through it in the answer above....

Comment: No worries. I figured it out! It works! I'll update my main post with what I came up with.